# openJPA does not react to @OrderBy

Tags: openjpa

I have a class with a

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@OrderBy(value="minAantal") Dit lijkt niet te werken.
private Collection<PrijsTabelItem> prijsTabelItems;
```

The property minAantal is an integer. When I persist an Object and recall it from the database, the Collection prijsTabelItem is not sorted.

I already tried to change the OneToMany to:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

but that does not make any difference.

Is this a problem in openJPA or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Enable sql trace openjpa.Log=SQL=trace to see if the @OrderBy is being honored. I'd also switch your Collection to be a List.

Comment: Thanks, that made clear that there was no select statement: I did not close the EntityManager. After closing it and creating a new EntityManager it works.